# Error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I began to study the "javascript".

in html source code

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <button id="test_button">Test</button>
    <p id="test">Hello World</p>

    <!-- script -->
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

in javascript source code

```
"use strict";

$(function() {
document.getElementById("test_button").onclick = test_click;
function test_click() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "HI";
}
});
```

Where's wrong?

Comment: You need to load the jQuery library in if you're going to use the '$'.

Comment: Make sure you have jQuery loaded as suggested by James above. Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/j55bhbhk/

Answer (score 4):

You need to include jQuery. Try adding this to your `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**`$`** is an alias for the jQuery library. In this case, you don't need jQuery at all. You can just execute that IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression) and it should work fine.

```js
"use strict";

(function() {
document.getElementById("test_button").onclick = test_click;
function test_click() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "HI";
}
})();
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <button id="test_button">Test</button>
    <p id="test">Hello World</p>

    <!-- script -->
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```